# GridView - Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, stored-procedures, gridview

I have this Stored Procedure:

```
USE [Events2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spUpdateRegistrantPaper]    Script Date: 11/20/2015 7:02:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateRegistrantPaper]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @RegistrantId int,
        @LocalNumber int,
        @LocalUnionEmail nvarchar(50),
        @DistrictId int,
        @CompletedByFirstName nvarchar(20),
        @CompletedByLastName nvarchar(25),
        @CompletedByPhone nvarchar(15),
        @FirstName nvarchar(20),
        @LastName nvarchar(25),
        @Position nvarchar(15),
        @Email nvarchar(50),
        @ShirtSize nvarchar(50),
        @Comments nvarchar(300)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE Registrant SET
        LocalNumberId = @LocalNumber,
        LocalUnionEmail = @LocalUnionEmail,
        DistrictId = @DistrictId,
        CompletedByFirstName = @CompletedByFirstName,
        CompletedByLastName = @CompletedByLastName,
        CompletedByPhone = @CompletedByPhone,
        FirstName = @FirstName,
        LastName = @LastName,
        Position = @Position,
        Email = @Email,
        ShirtSize = @ShirtSize,
        Comments = @Comments
        WHERE RegistrantId = @RegistrantId
END
```

And I have a GridView with an Edit and Update button.

```
  <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RegistrantId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalNumber" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalUnionEmail" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DistrictId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByFirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByLastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByPhone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Position" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ShirtSize" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
```

But I am getting this error:

> Procedure or function spUpdateRegistrantPaper has too many arguments
>   specified.

I don't see why...??? What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**

Here is full asp.net code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="viewregistrantpaper.aspx.cs" Inherits="viewreg" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<h1>View Registrant</h1>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrant"  
            CssClass="mGrid"  
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalNumberId" HeaderText="Local" 
                    SortExpression="LocalNumberId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalUnionEmail" HeaderText="Local Email" 
                    SortExpression="LocalUnionEmail" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DistrictId" HeaderText="District" 
                    SortExpression="DistrictId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByFirstName" HeaderText="Completed By First Name" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByFirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByLastName" HeaderText="Completed By Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByLastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByPhone" HeaderText="Completed By Phone" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByPhone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" 
                    SortExpression="Position" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
                    SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShirtSize" HeaderText="Shirt Size" 
                    SortExpression="ShirtSize" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" 
                    SortExpression="Comments" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
    <div style=" width:100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrant" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
            DeleteCommand="spDelRegistrant" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            InsertCommand="spInsRegistrantPaper" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            SelectCommand="spGetRegistrantPaper" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            UpdateCommand="spUpdateRegistrantPaper" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RegistrantId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalNumber" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalUnionEmail" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DistrictId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByFirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByLastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByPhone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Position" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ShirtSize" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RegistrantId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalNumber" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalUnionEmail" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DistrictId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByFirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByLastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByPhone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Position" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ShirtSize" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the correct DB `Events2` as per your Stored Proc?

Comment: Can you show the code that actually calls the procedure?

Comment: @Andrei - This looks like a `SqlDataSource` control, so we can't expect any code ;)

Comment: Yes it should be Events2. I just edited to add full code for asp.net page. This is all the code I have to make it work.

Comment: @RockOn - I still suspect you are hitting a wrong version of SP. Can you re-check the SP and your connection string DB name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you are using a lot of `BoundField`s in your GridView. The thing to know about these fields is that their values are added to the update/insert commands automatically. So for instance:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LocalNumberId" HeaderText="Local" 
    SortExpression="LocalNumberId" />
```

This will result in param `LocalNumberId` being added to the call of your stored proc. Since you already have just `LocalNumber` as a param, `LocalNumberId` turns out as an unexpected. Thus you have all parameters you explicitly declared in `UpdateParameters` tag as well as others which are in a BoundField.

Your options that I see here:

1. Make sure BoundFields represent accurately params you want in the stored proc, rename columns or stored proc params as needed.
2. Get rid of bound fields, use `TemplateFields` with `Eval` instead. Simple example:

   Instead of

   ```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalNumberId" HeaderText="Local" 
               SortExpression="LocalNumberId" />
   ```

   You would have

   ```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Local" SortExpression="LocalNumberId">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <%# Eval("LocalNumberId") %>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   ```
3. Manually write call to the stored proc as `UpdateCommand`, using only params you require

Comment: @RockOn, added a simple example

Comment: Perfect thanks! I added the tag `<ItemTemplate>` to your example, and it worked.